# What is difference between a upstream branch and remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

What is difference between a `upstream branch` and `remote tracking branch` ?
Is upstream branch the branch on the remote that is tracked by remote tracking branch ?

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen's answer is right. I'll just note here that the Git terminology probably could only be slightly more confusing if they had deliberately gone out of their way to make it confusing. :-) The terms "branch", "remote", and "tracking" all have one meaning but if you combine them, e.g., "remote-tracking branch", you get an only-slightly-related *different* meaning! It's maddening; the only sensible thing to do is to have a complete table of all meanings, or to stop using these rather crazy names. It's hard to make everyone else switch naming systems, so mostly we use the crazy names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the Git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) sums it up better than I could myself:

> Checking out a local branch from a remote-tracking branch automatically creates what is called a “tracking branch” (and the branch it tracks is called an “upstream branch”). Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically knows which server to fetch from and which branch to merge in.

A remote tracking branch, despite that the word `remote` appears its name, is actually not remote, it is completely local to your local Git repository.  It's main purpose is to serve as a proxy for the actual branch which exists on the remote (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.).  Most of your Git operations, e.g. `git merge`, `git rebase`, etc., involving the remote branch will actually use this (local) remote tracking branch.

The upstream branch, as the blurb above describes, is the actual remote Git branch which exists on the repo.  When other users pull a remote branch, their local Git will do a pull from this branch, and update the (local) remote tracking branch.

Comment: But what is upstream branch ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin The upstream is the true remote Git branch.  The tracking branch is basically your own local copy of that remote branch.  As such, your tracking branch can get out of date if things happen on the remote, and you don't sync up.

Comment: `git pull` will normally use this (local) remote tracking branch, but only after merging the remote branch on the server which it is tracking.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Of course, a pull does a fetch first, which involves going to the remote.  But, a `git merge` or `git rebase` is primarily a local thing AFAIK.

Comment: You are right concerning `merge` and `rebase`; but pull is different. The whole point of the normal pull is to sync with remote.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider `git pull = git fstch + git merge`, so of course it syncs with the remote.  Not sure what point you are trying to make here.

Comment: You make the correct point that "A remote tracking branch [...] is actually not remote, it is completely local [...]" . You then continue '"most of your Git operations, e.g. git pull, git merge, etc., involving the **remote branch** will actually use this **(local)** remote tracking branch.". In the context "remote branch" must be understood as "server", because you juxtapose it to "(local)". This juxtaposition is justified for merge (which does not access the server) but not for pull, which actually does. It would be better to say e.g. "most git operations *except* pull involve *only* ...".

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You're right, and I changed my language.